# I dont understand this error or how to fix it

Tags: matlab

I keep getting:

Index in position 1 exceeds array bounds.

Error in Finalprojectpt1 (line 42)
height = iCon(i,3);

I am not sure what to do as this is the first line with height in it, if i set height up prior as a variable to blank index, nothing changes. The .mat file is a 5x10 double if that helps. I also need to plot this after but I cant with the current error. Appologies if this doesnt make sense, im very new and lost.

```
load 'all_init_conditions.mat'


%% initial conditions
linit= length(all_init_conditions(1,:));
iCon(:,:) = all_init_conditions(:,:)';
%v0 velocity
%T0 Flight Path Angle
%h0 altitude
%x0 horizontal distance
%m0 mass
gMoon = 1.6;
isp = 255;

%Optimality score
iCon=[];
EndTime=[];
AltitudeScore = [];
%(1-hf)*100;
VelocityScore =  [];
%(1-(vf/2))*200;
GammaScore = [];
%(1-((pi/2)+Tf))*200;
TotalScore = [];

t = 0; 

Mathf = struct(); 

%calling EOM as dydt
dydt=@(t,iCon)GravityTurnEOM(t,iCon,gMoon,isp);
%%conditions



%% code part 1
%tstep
options = odeset('RelTol',1e-10);

for i=1:linit

    height = iCon(i,3);

    dt=0.2;


while height > 0.1
   tstep=0:0.2:dt;

    [t,iCon]=ode45(dydt,tstep,iCon(i,:),options);

    vary=[t,iCon];

    dt=dt+0.2;

    height=vary(end,4);
end
Tend = vary(end,1);
Vfinal = vary(end,2);
Gfinal = vary(end,3);
AltFinal = vary(end,4); 

EndTime(i) = Tend;

Mathf(i).output = vary;

%Calculate all different scores including TotalScore
VelocityScore(i) = (1-(Vfinal/2))*200;
GammaScore(i) = (1-((pi/2)+Gfinal))*200;
AltitudeScore(i) = (1-AltFinal)*100;

TotalScore(i) = AltitudeScore(i) + GammaScore(i) + VelocityScore(i); 

if Gfinal < (-95*(pi/180))||Gfinal > (-85*(pi/180))||Vfinal>1% convert to radians

AltitudeScore(i) = 0;
GammaScore(i) =0;
VelocityScore(i) =0;
TotalScore(i)=0;

end

end


% Looking for max value in TotalScore vector.
max=max(TotalScore(:));
%Find the position in TotalScore in which Max Score exists
find(TotalScore == MaxScore) = r;

BestStates = Mathf(r).output(:,2:6);

writematrix(BestStates,'MatrixBestStates.csv');
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means, that you're trying to access an element at an index which is bigger than the array's size.

At the beginning of your code you reinitiate the `iCon` to an empty (0x0) matrix. Thus your height calculation with `iCal(i,3)` fails.

```
linit= length(all_init_conditions(1,:));
iCon(:,:) = all_init_conditions(:,:)';
% ...
iCon=[]; % <-- this results in a 0x0 matrix
```

So just get rid of `iCon=[]`. On the topic of initializing array/matrix, instead of having "growing" arrays its better to init them with the expected size (better performance, lower computation time).

As an example:

```
AltitudeScore = zeros(size(iCon));
```

Additionally I would move the "Calculate all different scores including TotalScore" part out of the for-loop and not calculate them in every step. Have a look at Mathworks element-wise operators [cf. doc](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html)